# What happens to the Services when the application that started them gets uninstalled?

Tags: android, service

I am new to android dev. Recently I have come across the following question and couldn't find the answer. My question is if it is possible for a service to continue running even after the application that started the service gets uninstalled by the user. If yes, how? What happens to the services usually when the uninstall process of the application that started the services has been started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if it is possible for a service to continue running even after the application that started the service gets uninstalled by the user.

No.

> What happens to the services usually when the uninstall process of the application that started the services has been started?

The process is terminated and the app is uninstalled.

Comment: If the service was running on a different process other than the applications main process, would it be same?

Comment: @dupur: Yes. All standard SDK processes associated with an Android app are terminated as part of the app being uninstalled.